# Catching errors in AsyncTask unit test

Tags: android, junit, android-asynctask

I am trying to write a test for an async task where the **expected** result is that an error is thrown (in this case because a parameter has not been provided).

Normally I would just try/catch however this doesn't seem to work when the task is executed on a different thread.

current test code:

```
public class TokensAsyncTaskTest extends TestCase {

Context mockContext = new MockContext();

@Mock
TokensAsyncTask.OnResultListener mockListener;

@Mock
private APIManager apiManager;

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}


public void testNoToken() throws Exception {
    TokensAsyncTask task = getTask();
    try {
        task.execute();
        task.get();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
    verify(mockListener).onTokensReturned(null);
    verify(apiManager, never()).getObjectFromAPI(isA(String.class), isA(String.class), isA(String.class));
}

protected TokensAsyncTask getTask() {
    TokensAsyncTask task = new TokensAsyncTask(mockContext, mockListener, apiManager);
    return task;
}
```

This results in the error

> Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException''. Check device logcat for details

and never reaches the catch block.

Is there no way to handle this currently or is there a way to catch this?

Comment: It seems like trying to test the AsyncTask is just making things harder than they need to be.  Can't you just have the AsyncTask delegate to a model service object that you can then test directly? You can assume that the AsyncTask mechanism will "just work" because it's a framework class.  Then you don't have to deal with multithreading in your test.

Comment: I did consider that, but I don't like creating boilerplate to satisfy unit tests, and being that it is testing that a variable has been passed to execute() means that it is the implementation of the AsyncTask I want to test.

Comment: I would argue that it's not just separation to satisfy a unit test, but that it's good separation between your domain model and application concerns about what thread to run this operation on.  If you do in fact want to test the AsyncTask directly though, then you're right, it doesn't help.

Comment: Essentially all the call is doing is fetching from an API so there's not much logic other than 'are my inputs correct' (and throw an exception if not) and 'is there a valid response. The test is essentially checking the former condition and whatever way to extract it, you still need to check that parameter exists. If it were actual domain logic I would agree, you are better off separating the logic.